# Select не передаёт имя на обработчик

Tags: php, html, form

Есть такая форма

```html
 <form  action="appointmentreg.php" method="POST" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
  <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 control-label">ФИО пациента</label>
          <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
<input name="fio" type="text"  class="form-control" id="fio" value="">
                  </div>
                                            </div>
           <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 control-label">Телефон</label>
          <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
<input name="phone" type="text"  class="form-control" id="phone" value="">
                  </div>
                                            </div>
 <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 control-label">Дата приёма</label>
          <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
<input name="datea" type="text" class="form-control " id="cal_1" value="">
                  </div>
                                            </div>
 <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 control-label">Время приёма</label>

      <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
        <select name="timea" class="selectpicker show-tick form-control" id="basic" data-live-search="true">
          <option>08</option>
          <option>09</option>
          <option>10</option>
          <option>11</option>
          <option>12</option>
          <option>13</option>
          <option>14</option>
          <option>15</option>
          <option>16</option>
          <option>17</option>
          <option>18</option>
       </select>
      </div>  <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
        <select name="minuta" class="selectpicker show-tick form-control" id="minuta" data-live-search="true">
          <option>00</option>
    <option>05</option>
    <option>10</option>
          <option>15</option>
          <option>20</option>
          <option>25</option>
          <option>30</option>
          <option>35</option>
    <option>40</option>
    <option>45</option>
    <option>50</option>
    <option>55</option>
          
       </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="fiod" value="<?php echo $fiod; ?>">
    
    <input type="hidden" name="uid2" value="<?php echo $uid2; ?>">
 <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-left">Сохранить</button>
    </form>
```

И есть код обработчика

```
$timea = $_POST['timea'] ;
$minuta = $_POST['minuta'] ;
$sec = "00" ; 
$timeall = "$timea:$minuta:$sec";
echo $timeall ;
```

После сабмита формы получаю ошибку 
Notice: Undefined index: timea
Notice: Undefined index: minuta
Что может быть не так ?

Comment: обрамите Вашу "форму" из приведённого html кода тегом <form method="post"> или, если это сделано, приведите полный пример своей html разметки.

Comment: Хорошо. Приведу в тексте вопроса.

Comment: Код обработчик не стал полностью приводить так как думаю не важно это. Так как дело касается только 2 переменных

Comment: Ничего не забыли? http://htmlbook.ru/html/option/value

Comment: value ? ) Но в bootstrap selectpicker е нету value . И самое странное до этого ведь работал....и с этим тоже не работает (

Comment: откройте в браузере отладчик (f12) выберите вкладку Сеть или Network, нажмите на отправку формы и поглядите что в запросе. Если там есть данные формы и запрос был POST - значит сервер режет то что пришло, если там данных нет, либо запрос не POST - значит надо копать код страницы. Может быть js обработка идет перед отправкой или еще что.

Answer (score 0):

Тег **option** определяет значение пункта списка, которое будет отправлено на сервер. На сервер отправляется пара «имя=значение», где имя задается атрибутом name тега , а значение — атрибутом **value** выделенных пунктов списка. Значение может как совпадать с текстом пункта, так быть и самостоятельным. Также атрибут value применяется для получения значений данных через скрипты.

Говоря коротко то что находится между тегами   это лишь представление значения для UI. А на сервере вы работаете с **value**

Comment: Если не указать value - на сервер пойдет текст между <option></option>

Comment: а ведь с value тоже не работает